# How can I check if first character of a line is "*" in ANTLR4?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, lexer

I am trying to write a parser for a relatively simple but idiosyncratic language.

Simply put, one of the  rules is that comment lines are denoted by an asterisk *only* if that asterisk is the first character of the line.  How might I go about formalising such a rule in ANTLR4?  I thought about using:

```
START_LINE_COMMENT: '\n*' .*? '\n' -> skip;
```

But I am certain this won't work with more than one line comment in a row, as the newline at the end will be consumed as part of the `START_LINE_COMMENT`token, meaning any subsequent comment lines will be missing the required initial newline character, which won't work.  Is there a way I can perhaps check if the line starts with a `'*'` without needing to consume the prior `'\n'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matching a comment line is not easy. As I write one grammar per year, I had to grab to [The Definitive ANTLR Reference](https://pragprog.com/book/tpantlr2/the-definitive-antlr-4-reference) to refresh my brain. Try this :

```
grammar Question;

/* Comment line having an * in column 1. */

question
    :   line+
    ;

line
//    :   ( ID | INT )+
    :   ( ID | INT | MULT )+
    ;

LINE_COMMENT
    :   '*' {getCharPositionInLine() == 1}? ~[\r\n]* -> channel(HIDDEN) ;
ID  :   [a-zA-Z]+ ;
INT :   [0-9]+ ;
//WS  :   [ \t\r\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN) ;
WS  :   [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
MULT : '*' ;
```

Compile and execute :

```
$ echo $CLASSPATH
.:/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.6-complete.jar:
$ alias
alias a4='java -jar /usr/local/lib/antlr-4.6-complete.jar'
alias grun='java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig'
$ a4 Question.g4 
$ javac Q*.java
$ grun Question question -tokens data.txt 
[@0,0:3='line',<ID>,1:0]
[@1,5:5='1',<INT>,1:5]
[@2,9:12='line',<ID>,2:2]
[@3,14:14='2',<INT>,2:7]
[@4,16:26='* comment 1',<LINE_COMMENT>,channel=1,3:0]
[@5,32:35='line',<ID>,4:4]
[@6,37:37='4',<INT>,4:9]
[@7,39:48='*comment 2',<LINE_COMMENT>,channel=1,5:0]
[@8,51:78='* comment 3 after empty line',<LINE_COMMENT>,channel=1,7:0]
[@9,81:81='*',<'*'>,8:1]
[@10,83:85='not',<ID>,8:3]
[@11,87:87='a',<ID>,8:7]
[@12,89:95='comment',<ID>,8:9]
[@13,97:100='line',<ID>,9:0]
[@14,102:102='9',<INT>,9:5]
[@15,107:107='*',<'*'>,9:10]
[@16,109:110='no',<ID>,9:12]
[@17,112:118='comment',<ID>,9:15]
[@18,120:119='<EOF>',<EOF>,10:0]
```

with the following data.text file :

```
line 1
        line 2
* comment 1
    line 4
*comment 2

* comment 3 after empty line
 * not a comment
line 9    * no comment
```

Note that without the `MULT` token or `'*'` somewhere in a parser rule, the asterisk is not listed in the tokens, but the parser complains :

```
line 8:1 token recognition error at: '*'
```

If you display the parsing tree

```
$ grun Question question -gui data.txt
```

you'll see that the whole file is absorbed by one line rule. If you need to recognize lines, change the line and white space rules like so :

```
line
    :   ( ID | INT | MULT )+ NL
    |   NL
    ;

//WS  :   [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
NL  :   [\r\n] ;
WS  :   [ \t]+ -> skip ;
```